# Installing windows as a guest os on linux server

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I have a linux server ( Debian ) and I just have ssh access to it.
I install VirtualBox on it, Can I installing a windows as guest OS remotely only from ssh access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently run over 5 Virtual MS using VirtualBox and phpvirtualbox using lighttpd as a web server.

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Install apache2 or lighttpd
3. Download phpvirtualbox and move to htdocs
4. Access phpvirutalbox using web browser and manage your guest OS's

If you cannot install and run a web server on the system and truly only have SSH as access you can look at using the VBoxManage command

```
VBoxManage
```

[Chapter 8. VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)

Obviously you will need to have access to RDP ports in order to manage the guest OS via console.

http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/